# Fixing Cannot Find Symbol Google Cloud Messaging Error

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

In a cordova based project, I'm getting error `cannot find symbol GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);`

I tried many possible solutions marked as answers to different similar questions but none of those worked. Even there are some similar [issues](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/604) pointed out at [phonegap-plugin-push repo](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) but none is working in my case.

Two top rated solutions I found are:

- Completely remove google play services
- Upgrade google play services to the latest version

Removing cordova's *[google play services](https://github.com/appfeel/google-play-services)* plugin, produces more dependency errors for other plugins like *Google Universal Analytics*. I'm now trying to upgrade the plugin, but unable to do so as every fresh installation, installs version 19.0.3 by default. Is there any way to upgrade the plugin or fixing the overall issue?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that probably there's some file where version 19.0.3 of *google play services* plugin is hard coded as every fresh installation installs the same version. I uninstalled the plugin and then explored some common files and as a result found that there are following lines in **config.xml** and **package.json** files respectively:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplayservices" spec="~19.0.3" />`

`"cordovaPlugins": [
    ...
    "cordova-plugin-googleplayservices"
]`

I removed both of these lines and successfully rebuilt the project using `ionic build android`. This is how I get rid of this error.